# Python The script is executed only partially

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, ftp

Hi I have created this python script but it only runs in half and not completely, the part of the Ftp upload is not performed, how do I fix this script ?

```
import subprocess
import time

cmdline = ["cmd", "/q", "/k", "echo off"]
cmd = subprocess.Popen(cmdline, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
batch = b"""\
ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 1000 > nul
notepad.exe office-data.txt
"""
cmd.stdin.write(batch)
cmd.stdin.flush() # Must include this to ensure data is passed to child process
result = cmd.stdout.read()
print(result)

import ftplib

sftp = ftplib.FTP('ftp.example.com','userexample','passexample') # Connect
fp = open('office-data.txt','rb') # file to send
sftp.storbinary('STOR office-data.txt', fp) # Send the file

fp.close() # Close file and FTP
sftp.quit()
```

Comment: I'm guessing that ftp.example.com and those login details aren't legitimate, for starters

Comment: the FTP part is irrelevant, since the problem would occur with a simple `print` instead.

Comment: Don't use `shell=True`; you're already running cmd.exe manually.  End each line with `"\r\n"`, as cmd expects, or use `universal_newlines=True` with `str` input. Use `bufsize=0` to avoid having to `flush`, and avoid deadlock by using `result, err = cmd.communicate(batch)`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't exit from the command prompt so it stays active.

Quickfix: add `exit` at the end of your batch string:

```
batch = b"""\
ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 1000 > nul
notepad.exe office-data.txt
exit
"""
```

but it seems that you're overcomplicating things. You want to check if the site is alive, so just check return code from `ping`, and then run a system command to open your text file, for example like this (not the best but avoids the stdin/stdout hack):

```
cmd = subprocess.Popen("ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 1000", stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
rc=cmd.wait()
if rc:
    raise Exception("Cannot ping site")
txtfile = "office-data.txt"
os.system("notepad "+txtfile)
```

Comment: you made a mistake somewhere else. Adding `exit` to your string cannot trigger an error like that.